# fortran_free_source interrupts comment syntax coloring in vim

Tags: vim, comments, fortran

I am reading fortran 77 code (which I hate!) and in order to keep vim from coloring the lines weirdly after line 72, I included `let fortran_free_source=1` before the `syntax on` line in my .vimrc.

However, after doing this, all comments which begin with 'C' or 'c' are not colored the way comments should be colored. Only comments which begin with '!' are colored correctly. How should I edit my .vimrc file so that comments in the old fortran style are colored correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New answer:
Add to your .vimrc `let fortran_have_tabs=1` that should get rid of it. The only side effect will be that tabs are no longer highlighted.

Old answer:

I wouldn't know any direct solution for this but a dirty hack would be to copy the fortran.vim in your syntax folder and remove line 332:

```
    syn match fortranSerialNumber       excludenl "^.\{73,}$"lc=72
```

if you call it myfortran.vim (in your ~/.vim/syntax folder) you can use set syntax=myfortran. I'm sure there must be a more elegant way but this should work.

If you leave it as fortran.vim then only the file in ~/.vim/syntax will be loaded and not the one in /usr/yourvimdir/

Comment: hi! link fortranSerialNumber Normal ... would accomplish the similar effect without the hack. It would still match but wouldn't show.

Answer (score 2):

You're solving your problem in a wrong way. Vim colors the *past the 72th column* for a reason, for that is *invalid code*, to show you it would be ignored.

Anyways, *since I don't know what it is coloring from your description, so I'll guess it is  a string*, try

```
hi! link fortranSerialNumber fortranString
```

and let us know the results...

Comment: i have fortran free source as a parameter to the compiler so it is completely valid code.

Comment: @Laurbert515 - Yes, but for what reason? If it is Fortran77 code, written in fixed form (anf Fortran77 code could only be written in fixed form ... well, almost), then why "turn it into" >= F90 code? Leave it as F77, and let Vim treat it as such.

Comment: because i prefer not being told how long to make my lines?

Comment: @Laurbert515 - It goes with the language. Live with it. Or use it as free form, but then check out the description of the C comment and the ! comment. They're not the same. Seriously, I really don't see a problem with 72 character restriction (my free form lines are about that size anyway), enough for it to be of any bother ...

Comment: i'm so confused as to why you are barking up this tree. what do you care about my programming preferences? in fortran90 (my preferred flavor of fortran) there is no restriction and so that is what i am used to. when i have to work on other people's code in f77, i would like to be able to read and write the code as i see fit. it is pure preference and i have every right to it =)

Comment: @Laurbert515 - Language features are one thing, personal preferences are something else. 72th column is a language feature. As far as comments go, they're a similar problem. You can use one or the other, but you cannot expect for something to behave like you want it to, just like you don't like how it was designed to behave. In any case, do whatever you want ... you got my answer above, and this discussion is becoming less and less constructive.

Comment: @Laurbert515: I would reiterate, as someone who has to deal with large bodies of fixed-format Fortran, that the behavior is expected and intended. You should instead convert from F77 to F90 rather than mixing and matching. Life will be much easier and you'll run into far less compiler gotchas.

Comment: well, i'm working on code (a lot of it i might add) which is already in F77 that i did not write and already in free-format ... sooo ... not a lot i can do about that other than rewrite EVERYTHING or try to make the best of it with the word processors at my disposal

Comment: @Laurbert515 - Although there were compiler extensions which enabled one to do this, F77 was, by feature, a fixed format language. There was no such thing as a free format F77 (exceptions aside). In any case, if it is in F77 with no vendor extensions (language-wise), putting it in fixed format should be a matter of indentation (1-5 labels, 6 continuation column, 7-72th code columns) and perhaps an appropriate extension (.for, .f ?), depending on the compiler. No tabs. If it is F77 in free format, then by (some) definitions it is F90 code with (possibly) no F90 language features.

Comment: In any case, amongst developers such mixing of language features and fixed/free format is usually frowned upon. What compiler are you using to compile it, and what is the latest language revision - language features-wise (i.e. are there elements from F90 inside, or is it strictly F77 code in free format)? Skipping of course the fact that most of F77 code is also valid F90 code for now.

Comment: this has all become a crazy rabbit trail that is not producing much help. i'm not nearly as interested in the semantical differences between .f90 and .f77 as i am how to get vim to stop coloring characters past line 72 a different color.

Comment: @Laurbert515 - See below for Azrael's answer. Find its matching group and just link it to Normal highlighting group ...

Answer (score 0):

Put this in ~/.vimrc/after/syntax/fortran.vim:

```
syn match fortranComment excludenl "^[!c*].*$" contains=@fortranCommentGroup,@spell
syn match fortranComment excludenl "!.*$" contains=@fortranCommentGroup,@spell
```

This highlights all types of Fortran comments, regardless of other highlighting options like fixed or free source form.

Anything in ~/.vimrc/after/syntax/ runs after parsing the default syntax highlighting file. The two lines above are in my copy of fortran.vim, but are inside of `if` statements so they don't always take effect.

You could add a d inside the first line `"^[!cd*].*$"` if you want to highlight the non-standard "d" comment lines.