# Syntax highlighting of Fortran 77 comments not working in vim

Tags: vim, comments, fortran

I have a code written in Fortran 77 and I read it with vim. The code is written such that the comments are on lines starting with `c`, as is standard in Fortran 77. However, vim does not recognize them and therefore use a coloring syntax that makes the code very difficult to read! How can I overcome this?

I've seen that there is a [post with the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505125/fortran-free-source-interrupts-comment-syntax-coloring-in-vim). I have read the answers and tried the different solutions that have been suggested:

1. add `let fortran_have_tabs=1` to .vimrc
2. add

   ```
   syn match fortranComment excludenl "^[!c*].*$" contains=@fortranCommentGroup,@spell
   syn match fortranComment excludenl "!.*$" contains=@fortranCommentGroup,@spell
   ```

   to .vimrc

but they do not work for me. Does someone know why? Have I made a mistake somewhere? Otherwise, does anyone have a different suggestion?

Comment: What version of vim? Does it work if the file extension is .f?

Comment: Is it coloring anything?  Or are just the comments not colored?  If you try a Fortran 90 comment (!) does it color that?  I believe the vim Fortran highlighting routine looks at the first few lines of the file and determines if the file is fixed-format or not from that.  If your have some non-standard FORTRAN 77 things in the first few lines of the file, vim may be assuming the file is free-format and thus "c" would not be considered a comment.

Comment: It would be nice to see an example piece of code for testing in the question.

Comment: I just noticed <http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fortran_highlighting_problems>. It has some information for you. You might have to get into the bowels of the .vimrc file and syntax to find out what is going on otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

This is what works for me in my .vimrc:

```
let fortran_have_tabs=1
if has('syntax') && (&t_Co > 2)
    syntax enable
endif
```

The important part is most likely the `syntax enable` part. You may also need this:

```
filetype on
```

Also try typing in `:help ft-fortran-syntax` and reading that (or see here: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#ft-fortran-syntax). What I took away from that was that I needed to create the file `~/.vim/ftplugin/fortran.vim` and put this in it:

```
let s:extfname = expand("%:e")
if s:extfname ==? "f90"
  let fortran_free_source=1
  unlet! fortran_fixed_source
else
  let fortran_fixed_source=1
  unlet! fortran_free_source
endif
```

And also put this in your .vimrc:

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

That does the trick for me so that I can view and edit free-form and fixed-form with no problem.